# Why ByteBuffer doesn't provide method to read write boolean data type

Tags: java, nio

Why [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class doesn't provide method to read write boolean data type, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Boolean` is a 1-bit datatype. `ByteBuffer` works with bytes. You'll have to decide yourself how you'll represent a boolean as a byte (such as 0 for false and 1 for true, or 0 for false and non-zero for true).

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard on how a boolean should be written.  There is any number of workarounds such as writing 0 or 1, 0 or -1, `n` or `y` , `f` or `T`, or the strings "false" or "true", or whatever you like. Or as others have suggested you might want to write only one bit instead of using one or more bytes.

Answer (score 2):

It's because boolean (1 bit) is the only plain-old data data type that's *smaller* than a Byte (8 bits).

So you are motivated to pack booleans for efficiency. But the techniques for that are best left to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Because *on the wire* there is no such thing as a boolean data type. There are just bytes, which can be treated as (a) booleans, (b) sequences of ASCII, (c) taken 2 at a time as shorts, (d) taken 4 at a time as ints, (e) taken 8 at a time as longs, ...

Answer (score 0):

The `DataOutputStream` has a `writeBoolean(boolean v)` method.

Internally, it does `write(v ? 1 : 0)`. Using this convention, your code would look like

```
boolean v = <true|false>....
byteBuffer.put(v ? (byte)1 : (byte)0);
```